# Google Maps API: Mouseover works only during a certain time of the day

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I must say this is the weirdest error that I've ever caught during my programming adventures. I really have no idea why this is happening.

Basically, my application must receive some data from a Mysql Database and when the user clicks in a country, a infowindow must appear with some information (from the DB). The DB communication is working fine, the problem is: when I pass the mouse over a country, sometimes, the mouseover event isn't called, same thing with mouseout.

But sometimes? With what frequency? Here is the weirdest part: During specific times of the day. I'm brazilian, I work with UTC -3 here, if I acces my application at 18:00, it doesn't work, however if I access it during the morning, like 7 am, IT DOES WORK.

I really have no idea why this is happening, tryed to search online but found nothing...

Can someone help me? This is the code I'm using (no erros appears in the js console, the error happens in chrome, firefox, IE...):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
      var colors = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00'];
      var map
      var infowindow;

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(10, 0),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            myOptions);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


        // Initialize JSONP request
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?'];
        url.push('sql=');
        var query = 'SELECT name, kml_4326 FROM ' +
            '1foc3xO9DyfSIF6ofvN0kp2bxSfSeKog5FbdWdQ';
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
        url.push(encodedQuery);
        url.push('&callback=drawMap');
        url.push('&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ');
        script.src = url.join('');
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.appendChild(script);
      }

      function drawMap(data) {
        var rows = data['rows'];
        for (var i in rows) {
          if (rows[i][0] != 'Antarctica') {
            var newCoordinates = [];
            var geometries = rows[i][1]['geometries'];
            if (geometries) {
              for (var j in geometries) {
                newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j]));
              }
            } else {
              newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
            }
            //var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            var country = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths: newCoordinates,
              //strokeColor: colors[randomnumber],
              strokeOpacity: 0,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              //fillColor: colors[randomnumber],
              fillOpacity: 0
            });

        infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ''
        });

            google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', function() {
              alert("HIIIIII JOW");
              this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0.3});
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseout', function() {
              this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 0});
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'click', function(event) {
                var lat = event.latLng.lat();
                var lng = event.latLng.lng();

                initialize2(lat,lng);

            });
            country.setMap(map);
          }
        }
      }

      function constructNewCoordinates(polygon) {
        var newCoordinates = [];
        var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
        for (var i in coordinates) {
          newCoordinates.push(
              new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
        }
        return newCoordinates;
      }


      function initialize2(lat,lng){
        var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng+ "&sensor=true&language=en";
        jQuery.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.results[0].address_components.length; i++){
            //var formatted = results[0].formatted_address;//.short_name
            var countryName
            var shortname = data.results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
            var longname = data.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
            var type = data.results[0].address_components[i].types;
            if (type.indexOf("country") != -1){
                if (isNullOrWhitespace(shortname)){
                    countryName = shortname;
                }
                else{
                    countryName = longname;
                }
            }
        }
        var lat2;
        var lng2
        geocoder.geocode( {'address' : countryName}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat2 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lng2 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                //alert(results[0].geometry.location);//map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                //alert(lat2+','+lng2);
                var array = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;

                var str = 'Nenhuma exchange cadastrada neste país!';

                for(var i = 0;i<array.length;i++){

                    if(countryName==array[i][0]){
                        var string = 'country_volume.php?country=' + countryName;
                      str = '<center><strong>'+array[i][0]+'</strong></center>' +
                            '<strong>Número de Exchanges: </strong>' + array[i][1] + '</br>' +
                            '<strong>Volume: </strong>' + array[i][2] + '</br>' +
                            '<strong>Ranking Mundial: </strong> ' + array[i][3] + 'º' + '</br>' +
                            '<strong>Porcentagem Mundial (%): </strong> ' + array[i][4] + '%' + '</br>' +
                            '<a href='+string+'>' + 'Mais Informações' + '</a>';
                    }

                }

                if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
                infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: str,
                    map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat2,lng2)
                });

            }
        });

        });
      }

    function isNullOrWhitespace(text) {
        if (text == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return text.replace(/\s/gi, '').length < 1;
    }


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you are getting an error from the FusionTables API v1 like `"Daily Limit Exceeded"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may exceeded the daily `quota` of Fusion Tables API:

The default request quota limits are the following:

25,000 requests per day per API project, where reads count as one request and writes count as five requests.

30 write requests per minute per table
You may request more quota at the `Google APIs Console` under the "Quotas" tab.

The storage quota limits are:

- 100 MB per table
- 250 MB total among all your tables

For more details, please refer to [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#quota).

Comment: Thanks a lot man, indeed I was using a key that was from the editor of the example, not my own lol